# Use same Foreign Key in derived class with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some issues with Entity Framework: I have a base class with two derived classes. In the other hand, I have a class with three List each containing one of the mentioned classes:

```
public class Base {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Datetime date { get; set; }
}

public class Derived1: Base{
}

public class Derived2: Base{
}

public class Container {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Base> base { get; set; }
    public List<Derived1> derived1 { get; set; }
    public List<Derived2> derived2 { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is for Base Derived1 and Derived2 to use the same foreign key to Container. And in Container I want the List of Base aggregate his List of Derived1 and Derived2. But I can't figured out how to do that. Normally, all derived classes from base will use the same foreign key but every time i try this code Entity framework creates one foreign key for each class. Here it is not a big deal but Base, Derived1, and Derived2 should share the same foreign key to two other classes and it would be really complex for actually nothing if It refuse to use the same foreign key (I will have 9 column instead of 3).

Comment: can you reword `And in Container I want the List of Base agregate his List of Derived1 and Derived2`, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Excuse me. I mean that, if there is a Derived1 object in Container's derived1 List, it must also be in his base List.